# Temporarily change multiple href attributes

Tags: jquery, wordpress, replace, attributes, restore

I am needing to temporarily disable multiple links and give them a new function instead.
They are links in a nav menu, which when on mobile become buttons that show drop downs, instead of take the user to a page. (this is fine because the page they take the user to is kind of redundant)

example:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="xyz"> FIRST LINK </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="zyx"> SECOND LINK </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="abc"> THIRD LINK </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So I plan to have a function that temporarily changes the href attributes to "#" while the window is smaller than 900px. Then if it is wider, the function does not run.

This is easy, but the challenge is that when I resize from < 900px to > 900px the original href attribute values aren't restored. How can I have them restored?

p.s. this is part of a wordpress menu, so you have to account for it's dynamic naming etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="xyz" class="navg" data-hrf=""> FIRST LINK </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="zyx" class="navg" data-hrf=""> SECOND LINK </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="abc" class="navg" data-hrf=""> THIRD LINK </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function(){

     function size_changed(){
         var width = $(window).width();
         if(width <= 900){

              // less then 900 so remove href with #
              $('.navg').each(function(){
                   var old = $(this).attr('href');
                   $(this).attr('data-hrf', old);   // store real href in data-hrf attribute
                   $(this).attr('href', '#');
              }); 

         }else{

             // more then 900 so restore
             $('.navg').each(function(){
                   var old = $(this).attr('data-hrf');
                   if(old != "" ) $(this).attr('href', old);  
             }); 

         }  // if __width

    } // will call everytime when you change the screen size

    // Now set this function as width change handler

   $(window).resize(function() {

         size_changed();

   });            

   // What if screen size is 500px alredy so call this funciton at starting the page
   size_changed();

 }); // document _ready
</script>
```

Thanks :) , there may be some spelling mistakes because i did not test this code, but it will work ;)

Comment: Woohoo! This did the trick!
Thank you very much!!! I had been on the right track but missed the .each()